# rsync for backup: Do I need troublesome user/1000/gvfs

Tags: permissions, backup, rsync, clone

I would like to use rsync as a backup solution; I am syncing the contents of my machine to an external hard-drive.  If my machine crashes, I want to restore another machine as close as possible to the one I currently have, since I have downloaded and customized a whole bunch of software for my research.  Reinstalling and customizing would take an enormous amount of time and effort.

When I run this dry-run command (replaced with real, but very long, file paths):

```
sudo rsync --dry-run -azv --delete --exclude-from '/exclude/list/file.txt' "/" "my/backup/location"
```

I get the error

```
rsync: readlink_stat("/run/user/1000/gvfs") failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]
```

I can of course avoid this error by excluding /run/user/1000/gvfs.  In fact, upon exclusion, I get no more errors.

However, as I said, I want to be able to use this sync in the event that my machine crashes and I want the new machine to work just like the old (or as close as possible).

Do I need this /run/user/1000/gvfs?  If so, how can I properly clone it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't include `/run` in my backups as its entire contents are wiped at every boot.  Its contents only exist for the benefit of currently running processes.

The same applies to `/tmp` and `/var/run`.  It is optional for `/var/cache` and `/var/tmp` in the sense that data in `/var/cache` and `/var/tmp` is preserved across reboots but *can* be deleted between boots with no consequences.  So I don't include any of the above mentioned directories in backups.

In this case `/run/user/1000/gvfs` is not a normal directory and is placed into the directory tree by the FUSE system to contain mount points of current temporary disk mounts set up by a regular user, such as, for example, when plugging in a USB drive while in a graphical desktop.  As with the rest of `/run`, you don't need to back it up.